# qgis-bin.exe is not responding at startup

Tags: qgis-3, windows-10

Whenever I open up qgis, it always does this:
[image]

I'm really new to this, so please bear with me:

I tried a whole lot of things, I uninstalled and reinstalled almost 10 times, and I'm starting to get desperate. I tried the standalone installer and the OSGeo4W installer, but they both have the same result. I have a 64-bit Windows 10 computer, and I downloaded the 64-bit option for QGIS 3.8.1, so I'm not sure what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the fact that you have different versions of qgis installed, I had the same issue when trying to run Qgis 3 while having my python environment set for Qgis 2.18.

I solved it by running these commands before launching qgis 3:

```
setx PYTHONHOME "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37"
setx PYTHONPATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\DLLs"
```